# How to Get/Set Multiple Checkbox Value from/to Choice Fields using REST API in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

How to get/set multiple Checkbox value from/to Choice field using REST API.

Appreciate any reply in advance.

Thanks,
MJ

Answer (score 0):

We can use CSOM

**Get value:**

```
<script>
    var item;
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetListItem, "sp.js");  
    function GetListItem(){
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("<list>");
        item = list.getItemById(<itemId>);
        clientContext.load(item);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
        }
        function onSuccess() {
            var checkboxValues = item.get_item("<checkbox column>");
            //operations
            console.log(checkboxValues);
        }
        function onFailure() {
            console.log('Failure!');
        }
</script>
```

**Set value:**

```
<script>
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(UpdateListItem, "sp.js");  
    function UpdateListItem(){
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();

        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('<list>');
        var item = list.getItemById(<itemID>);
        //set multi-choice field 
        item.set_item('<checkbox column>', '<value1>', '<value2>');
        item.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
    }
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("Item updated");
    }
    function onFailure() {
        console.log('Failure!');
    }
</script>
```